# command line websocket client for Raspberry Pi2- no browser required implementation?

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, client, raspberry-pi2

Send data read from GPiO to server, not only with WIFI, but also on mobile network outside anywhere. I dont have and dont want to deal with setting a public address for RPi2, so this is why I need RPi2 to be client, sending data thru websockets to server on public address. It could be node.js, python, PHP client - server, as long as it is without of the need for a browser at the client side RPi2. Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Additionally, can you please explain how would "server side node.js client" work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An (incomplete) list of libraries with websocket support

For Python, you could look at:

- [Tornado Web](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)
- [Twisted Matrix](https://twistedmatrix.com)
- [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/python/)
- [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/)

For node.js you could look at:

- [socket.io](http://socket.io/)
- [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js)

Also, you should consider editing your question. Just ask one at a time. Your second question you should research yourself, a little googling would get a link or two to a nice article explaining what you would like to know.